# Exporting a Scipy sparse matrix from Python2.7 to Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, sparse-matrix, mat-file

I have a very large Scipy sparse (csr) matrix. I can't use `M.toarray()` since it triggers `ValueError: array is too big.` Is there a way of saving a Scipy sparse matrix in Python to be read in Matlab? I need some tools that are available in Matlab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scipy's Mat file format tools support sparse matrices:

```
from scipy import sparse, io
m = sparse.rand(50000,50000,density=1e-8)
io.savemat('dump.mat', dict(m=m))
```

And in matlab:

```
>> load dump
```